# What goes in between { and } when writing BNF?

Tags: parsing, yacc, bnf, parser-generator, happy

I'm having some trouble with BNF. I can't tell what seems to be the standard way of doing things (if there is one), and whether or not there are types like char or int or whatever already built in.

However, my main problem is not understand how the part of the BNF in curly braces works.
Given something like:

```
exp    : term                           {$$ = $1;}  
| exp '+' term                   {$$ = $1 + $3;}  
| exp '-' term                   {$$ = $1 - $3;}  
;
```

(This was handily stolen from somewhere, and is for yacc / C)

What are the things in the curly braces actually saying? I've looked at a similar thing for the happy parser generator too, and been similarly confused.

Comment: Oh, and this isn't actually BNF.

Comment: @drachenstern: Whilst this question is primarily being asked because I'm looking at BNF because I'll have to be writing something for Happy to create a parser for a toy language for a compiler assignment, it's not really a homework question itself. I didn't understand the stuff I was looking at when I was googling, hence the asking. So it's not homework, but it is related to work set for my degree. Even then, it's not like I'm asking someone to do work for me, I'm after an explanation.

Comment: ~ That's cool. I just know that it's common for people to pass of their homework on here, and BNF questions + rep of 67 would make you a good candidate for having done so. But yes, that's a tad unfair. Hence I just tossed it out as a question. Thanks for clarification. ~~ Besides, kudos on doing research before you actually have to deal with it in school. `;)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to distinguish between BNF in general (and EBNF) and the Yacc syntax.  What the braces mean in BNF varies with dialect; it often means 'choose one of the alternatives', or it can be associated with repetition, or both.  In EBNF (ISO 14977:1996), '{ ... }' means repeat zero or more times, and '{ ... }-' means repeat one or more times (and why that is a '-' and not a '+' is mysterious).  The IETF uses [RFC-5234](http://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc5234/) and its dialect of BNF does not use '{}' at all.

In a Yacc grammar, though, the braces enclose the actions to be performed when the rule is matched (reduced in the jargon).  So, the '`{$$ = $1;}`' action means 'assign the value matched by 'term' to the result of reducing 'exp ::= term' (using another variant of BNF).

Answer (score 3):

The stuff within curly braces is actually C code that is executed when the corresponding rule is parsed. The `$` symbols are placeholders that are replaced with the actual values parsed by yacc: `$$` is the result you wish to compute, while `$1` to `$n` represent the values of the symbols on the right-hand side of the rule.

For example, the rule `exp '+' term { $$ = $1 + $3; }`, `$1` refers to the `exp` and `$3` is the `term`, so this says that when this rule is parsed, add `exp` and `term` to get the result.